# How to set up a travis.yml file for building a python wrapper on both Linux and OS X

Tags: python, linux, macos, travis-ci

How do I set up a `travis.yml` file for building a python wrapper which requires a compiler and `boost-python` on OS X as well as on Linux.

[This](https://github.com/sudoankit/nixpy/blob/master/.travis.yml) is my current `travis.yml` file which sadly fails.

Please guide me to modify the file for successful build.

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/